# How to make a line that divides a box

Tags: html, css

I have a question, how can I do this division of a box with css?
Something like I present in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Please add code of what you have tried first.

Comment: @frnt I do not have code, I have no idea how to do it, that's why I'm looking for help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, let me know if you need any explanation...

```css
.wrap {
border: 1px solid black;
background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495480024026-9dd2033e4b63?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=822&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=);
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrap:before {
      content: '';
      position:absolute;
      width:50%;
      height:400px;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
      transform: skewX(-15deg);
      background: white;
      z-index: 1;
}
  
.content {
  z-index: 3;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `flexbox` and `transform` properties.

here's a solution

```css
.container{
 display: flex;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
}
.left, .right{
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
}
.divider{
 width: 1px;
  background: gray;
  transform: rotate(6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
  Left
 </div>
 <div class="divider">
 
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  Right
 </div>
</div>
```

here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttyL9nz7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div
{
    border:2px solid;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;

}
.divide
{
    border:2px solid;
    border-width: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="divide">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your box with divide the box in two